# How to Round Up Years in Joda-Time

Tags: java, date, datetime, rounding, jodatime

Is there an existing way in [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) to round up years?

Say you have a DateTime startDate = 10-18-2016 and an DateTime  endDate = 12-18-2017. I would like that to round up to 2 years.

Currently, when I do:

```
Years yearsBetween = Years.yearsBetween(startDate, endDate);
```

I get yearsBetween = 1. Is there a simple way to fix this using Joda Time or do I need to write a custom method to handle this?

Comment: You could add a year minus a day to the endDate.

Comment: Why dont you use just an simple calculation?   `int years = (int) Math.ceil((double) Days.daysBetween(startDate, endDate).getDays()/365);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

- Move the start date to first of its year.
- Move the end date to first of its *following* year.

## Half-Open

Joda-Time uses the Half-Open approach to spans of time, where the beginning is *inclusive* and the ending is *exclusive*. So a year starts from the January 1 of the year in question and runs up to, but does not include, January 1 of the following year.

So you want dates in 2016-2017 to be two years, move the starting date to the first day of the year, and move the ending date to the first year of its *following* year.

We convert to `LocalDate` as we do not care about time-of-day for this calculation of years.

```
LocalDate start = startDate.toLocalDate().withDayOfMonth( 1 ).withMonthOfYear( 1 );  // Move to first of same year.
LocalDate stop = endDate.toLocalDate().withDayOfMonth( 1 ).withMonthOfYear( 1 ).plusYears(1);  // Move to first of *following* year.
```

Then perform your same calculation with `Years`.

```
Years yearsBetween = Years.yearsBetween( start , stop );  // Half-Open, beginning is inclusive while ending is exclusive.
int years = yearsBetween.getYears();  // Plain integer.
```

Results in `2` for any dates in 2016 (moved to 2016-01-01) and 2017 (moved to 2018-01-01).

---

## java.time

FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

This work is a bit simpler in java.time. The [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) interface provides for classes to manipulate date-time values. The [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) class (note the plural `s`) provides several implementations. These make provide for getting the first of the year and the first of the next year.

By `Zdt` here, I refer to the `ZonedDateTime` objects you might have in hand. This class represents a moment on the timeline in a particular time zone (`ZoneId`) with a resolution of nanoseconds. From the `ZonedDateTime` object we convert to a `LocalDate`, and then apply a pair of `TemporalAdjuster` objects to move to first of the year and of the following year.

```
LocalDate start = yourStartingZdt.toLocalDate().with( TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfYear() );
LocalDate stop = yourEndingZdt.toLocalDate().with( TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfNextYear() );
```

The java.time classes do not include the equivalent of the Joda-Time [`Years`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Years.html) class. If desired, you can add the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project to your app to extend java.time with additional classes that include a [`Years`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Years.html) class.

Alternatively, we can get the number of years via the `Period` class.

Like Joda-Time, java.time classes including `Period` use the Half-Open approach to spans of time. I advise using Half-Open yourself consistently in all your date-time work as it will make your code over all simpler and less error-prone.

```
Period p = Period.between( start , stop );
int years = p.getYears();
```

Results in `2` for any dates in 2016 (moved to 2016-01-01) and 2017 (moved to 2018-01-01).

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Well explained answer with exhaustive API coverage, but DOES NOT calc a round up as requested by original poster. Two dates with difference exactly one year or less then one year are calculated as 2 as well. Luckily this behavior is clearly stated in your answer. But for me and everyone seeking a round up the correct one is the answer by Jonathan Doyle.

Answer (score 2):

This was mentioned in one of the comments above and worked for me:

```
LocalDate startLocalDate = new LocalDate(startDate)
LocalDate endLocalDate = new LocalDate(endDate).plusYears(1).minusDays(1)

int yearsBetween = Years.yearsBetween(startLocalDate, endLocalDate).Years
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for everyone looking for a round up in years.

Comment: @Gandalf How does this code round up? The [Javadoc](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Years.html#yearsBetween-org.joda.time.ReadableInstant-org.joda.time.ReadableInstant-) says this method counts whole years. That means no rounding.

Comment: Is the `.Years` at the end of last line a typo?

Comment: @BasilBourque you are right, `yearsBetween` counts whole years. The "rounding" is achieved by this counting in combination with the `.plusYears(1).minusDays(1)` on the `endDate`.  `.Years` at the end is a typo. It has to be `.getYears()` instead.

Comment: The same "round up" can be achieved using methods of the `java.time` API which are quite similar to the JodaTime ones. `int yearsBetween = Period.between(startDate, endDate.plusYears(1).minusDays(1)).getYears()`